# Как "сохранить картинку для web" средствами Bash (используя только консоль Linux)?

Tags: shell, изображения, сервер, bash, linux

Есть целые альбомы с мероприятий, которые надо выложить на сайт. Они переданы фотографом в исходном формате.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать удаление информации о фотоаппарате, и сжатие, и возможно уменьшение до какого-нибудь типового размера (фотографии как вертикальные, так и горизонтальные)...
Пока всё делаю вручную, не знаю, как это автоматизировать...

(Циклы перебора всех файлов в папке мне не надо, уже умею, умею делать resize, но до полной автоматизации далеко.)

*Спасибо за подсказки.*

Comment: Вот здесь довольно подробно http://habrahabr.ru/post/154683/

Comment: Кстати, ImageMagic же.

Например convert file.jpg -resize 1280x800 file-out.jpg

Comment: [Как уменьшить размер фотографий. Массовое сжатие фотографий в командной строке](https://zalinux.ru/?p=7787)

Answer (score 0):

В общем и целом сохранить все фото на диск со страницы можно как-то так: `curl 'example.com/page.html' | egrep -i '(jpe?g|png)' | sed -e s@.*img[ \t\n\r]+?src=['"].+?['"]@@ig | wget -i -`. За верность регекспов не ручаюсь, но вроде работать должно.

Если сразу надо и преобразовывать, то следует помнить что результаты в пайпах ходят не построчно а целиком, поэтому надо чтото типа `curl 'example.com/page.html' | egrep -i '(jpe?g|png)' | sed -e s@.*img[ \t\n\r]+?src=['"].+?['"]@@ig | {while read l; do wget -q -i - -O ${basename $l}; echo $l; exiftool -EXIF= ${basename $l}; convert ... }` и так далее...